# functional programming modify two items in an array

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

I am looking into functional programming where I have the following code so far:

```
const R   = require('ramda')
const original = {
  words: [
    { duration: '0.360000', name: 'Arthur', position: '0.660000' },
    { duration: '0.150000', name: 'the',    position: '1.020000' },
    { duration: '0.380000', name: 'rat',    position: '1.170000' },
    { duration: '0.770000', name: '.',      position: '1.550000' }
  ]
}

// 1. convert position and duration to int and multiply by 100
const makeInteger = a => parseFloat(a) * 100

const words = R.lensPath(['words'])
log('position', R.over(words, R.map(R.over(position, makeInteger)), original).words)
```

returns:

```
position: [
    {
        duration: '0.360000',
        name: 'Arthur',
        position: 66
    },
    {
        duration: '0.150000',
        name: 'the',
        position: 102
    },
    {
        duration: '0.380000',
        name: 'rat',
        position: 117
    },
    {
        duration: '0.770000',
        name: '.',
        position: 155
    }
]
```

How do I modify both `duration` and `position` in the same function in order to make them integers?

Following that, I would have this function where I pass an index and update all the `positions` following that point.

Basically I like to shift the 'position' offset depending on the object where the 'duration' was modified?

```
const pos = R.over(words, R.map(R.over(position, makeInteger)), original)
const y = (i) => R.slice(i, Infinity, pos.words)
const foo = R.adjust(R.add(-2), 0, y(1))
log(foo)
```

And I got

```
[
    NaN,
    {
        duration: '0.150000',
        name: 'the',
        position: 102
    },
    {
        duration: '0.380000',
        name: 'rat',
        position: 117
    },
    {
        duration: '0.770000',
        name: '.',
        position: 155
    }
]
```

So I am kind of stuck on how to offset the position.

Any advice is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this, `evolve` and `splitAt` are your buddies:

```
const {
  lensProp, lensIndex, splitAt, compose,
  curry, flatten, add, map, multiply,
  over, evolve
} = require('ramda')

const original = {
  words: [
    { duration: '0.360000', name: 'Arthur', position: '0.660000' },
    { duration: '0.150000', name: 'the',    position: '1.020000' },
    { duration: '0.380000', name: 'rat',    position: '1.170000' },
    { duration: '0.770000', name: '.',      position: '1.550000' }
  ]
}

const words = lensProp('words')
const snd = lensIndex(1)

const makeInt =
  compose(multiply(100), parseFloat)

const updateProps =
  evolve({ duration: makeInt, position: makeInt })

const offsetPos =
  offset => evolve({ duration: add(offset), position: add(offset) })

const wordsToInt =
  over(words, map(updateProps))

const offsetTail = curry(
  (offset, list) => over(snd, map(offsetPos(offset)))(list)
)

const applyOffset = curry(
  (indx, offset, list) => compose(
    flatten,
    offsetTail(offset),
    splitAt(indx)
  )(list)
)

const offsetWords = curry(
  (indx, offset, obj) =>
    over(words, applyOffset(indx, offset))(obj)
)

const flow =
  compose(offsetWords(2, -2), wordsToInt)

log(flow(original))
```

Comment: nice one, this is perfect

Comment: The answer by @scott-sauyet is pretty darn good. his use of `lift` with `concat`(well with any n-ary > 1 function) is a super powerful pattern for ramda when working with lists.

Answer (score 1):

Another version, modelled on the one from [@Ian Hoffman-Hicks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2093271/), but with a slightly different public API (`flow` takes all three parameters) and several fewer intermediate functions, looks like this:

```
const wordsLens = lensProp('words') 

const makeInt = compose(multiply(100), parseFloat)

const offsetWords = curry((idx, offset, obj) => over(
  wordsLens, 
  lift(concat)(
    take(idx), 
    compose(
      map(evolve({position: add(offset)})), 
      drop(idx)
    )
  ), 
  obj
))

const flow = curry((idx, offset, obj) => offsetWords(
  idx, 
  offset, 
  over(
    wordsLens, 
    map(evolve({duration: makeInt, position: makeInt})), 
    obj
  )
))

flow(2, -2, original)
```

You can see this in action on the **[Ramda REPL](http://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.22.1#?const%20original%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20words%3A%20[%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20duration%3A%20%270.360000%27%2C%20name%3A%20%27Arthur%27%2C%20position%3A%20%270.660000%27%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20duration%3A%20%270.150000%27%2C%20name%3A%20%27the%27%2C%20%20%20%20position%3A%20%271.020000%27%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20duration%3A%20%270.380000%27%2C%20name%3A%20%27rat%27%2C%20%20%20%20position%3A%20%271.170000%27%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20duration%3A%20%270.770000%27%2C%20name%3A%20%27.%27%2C%20%20%20%20%20%20position%3A%20%271.550000%27%20%7D%0A%20%20]%0A%7D%0A%0A%0Aconst%20wordsLens%20%3D%20lensProp%28%27words%27%29%0A%0Aconst%20makeInt%20%3D%20compose%28multiply%28100%29%2C%20parseFloat%29%0A%0Aconst%20offsetWords%20%3D%20curry%28%28idx%2C%20offset%2C%20obj%29%20%3D%3E%20over%28%0A%20%20wordsLens%2C%20%0A%20%20lift%28concat%29%28%0A%20%20%20%20take%28idx%29%2C%20%0A%20%20%20%20compose%28%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20map%28evolve%28%7Bposition%3A%20add%28offset%29%7D%29%29%2C%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20drop%28idx%29%0A%20%20%20%20%29%0A%20%20%29%2C%20%0A%20%20obj%0A%29%29%0A%0Aconst%20flow%20%3D%20curry%28%28idx%2C%20offset%2C%20obj%29%20%3D%3E%20offsetWords%28%0A%20%20idx%2C%20%0A%20%20offset%2C%20%0A%20%20over%28%0A%20%20%20%20wordsLens%2C%20%0A%20%20%20%20map%28evolve%28%7Bduration%3A%20makeInt%2C%20position%3A%20makeInt%7D%29%29%2C%20%0A%20%20%20%20obj%0A%20%20%29%0A%29%29%0A%20%0Aflow%282%2C%20-2%2C%20original%29)**.

This version also used [`evolve`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#evolve), although it chooses [`take`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#take) and [`drop`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#drop) over [`splitAt`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#splitAt).  This might or might not be worth considering for you, but it at least shows a different approach.

Comment: thanks for the response, is really good and have learned more.

Answer (score 0):

For you first quesion, that's easy.

```
const parsedList = words.map(word => {
    return {
        duration:parseInt(word.duration)*100,
        name,word.name,
        position: parseInt(word.position)*100
    }
})
```

.map is a new ES6 function that loops over an array, and then returns a new array. (Doesn't mutate the array it's mapping, which is functional programming 101)

For your second one, forgive me if I'm wrong, but it sounds like either .filter or .push would work.